# How to include a Partial but only if it wasn't yet included?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, partial-views

I use `ASP.NET MVC5` together with `knockout.js`. I have several `knockout.js` templates, orginized into partial views. When I have a component in a view or partial view, which needs one or more specific template, I include the corresponding templates with `Html.Partial`. However, there is a problem I need to solve: this way, if a component itself is in a partial, and I have two or more components included in a View, the templates will get included twice or more times, which is undesirable.

I would like to achieve that whenever I need to include templates from partials, I wouldn't have to worry about wether they were already included or not. I could include the same partial with templates two or three times, but at the end, it would appear only once in the rendered View.

Is there any kind of bulit-in or third party solutions to this problem?

Comment: try using AMD loaders such as require JS.

Comment: There's no way to achieve this with Razor. Razor doesn't keep a running tally of what views it's rendered. If you include a partial it will blindly render it, whether it's the first time or the hundredth.

Comment: Thanks, yes, unfortunately this was my guess too. In the meantime I'm working on a helper extension method to make it possible. My plan is to track the rendered partials for the current request, so I can know if I have to cancel the base Partial method. If I manage to put it together I will answer my question.

Comment: I've had this same issue. Basically, I created an HTML extension that uses ViewData to store a list of templates. Then at the bottom of my layout view I render all of the templates. I can't post code right now, but I will once I'm back at my desk.

Comment: @shailendrakumar, I use require.js to load my scripts, how would you do use it to load html views?

Comment: @Jeff thank you, that sounds better than my idea. Anyway I think it coud be possible with AMD with some additional server configuration (render views without explicit controller actions), but currently I'm not using AMD in this project at all, and wouldn't like to add this complexity for only this problem.

Comment: @Jeff, you can use requirejs-text to load partials based on some conditions in javascript. Here is the link: https://github.com/requirejs/text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  This is how I solved it.  I don't love this solution, but it works.  If there's a better way I'd love to hear it.

```
public static class PartialExtension
    {
        public static void AddPartial(this HtmlHelper html, string partialLocation)
        {
            //Get a name for the template.  This is used to identify the template and
            //to ensure that a blank location has not been sent it.
            var partialName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(partialLocation);
            if (partialName == null)
                throw new Exception("The partial location can not be null");

            //Get the extension and directory.  If the location doesn't specify
            //a directory, like the location is in the current directory, then
            //we need to remove the extension.  Not sure why, but html.Partial()
            //throws an exception if you don't.
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(partialLocation);
            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(partialLocation);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dir) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extension) == false)
                partialLocation = partialLocation.Replace(extension, "");

            var tmpBag = html.ViewBag;
            tmpBag.TbdTemplates = tmpBag.TbdTemplates as Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> ?? new Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>();

            //Only add this template once.
            if (((Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>)tmpBag.TbdTemplates).ContainsKey(partialName)) return;

            //FYI: because html.Partial can call this recursively, we want to set the item in the dictionary
            //as soon as possible.  Then we call Partial().  The final call to that method will be what is 
            //set as the value in the dictionary.
            ((Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>)tmpBag.TbdTemplates)[partialName] = MvcHtmlString.Create("");

            var tmpHtml = html.Partial(partialLocation, html.ViewData);
            ((Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>)tmpBag.TbdTemplates)[partialName] = tmpHtml;
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString WritePartials(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            var tmpBag = html.ViewBag;
            tmpBag.TbdTemplates = tmpBag.TbdTemplates as Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString> ?? new Dictionary<string, MvcHtmlString>();

            if (tmpBag.TbdTemplates == null) return MvcHtmlString.Create("");

            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var value in tmpBag.TbdTemplates.Values)
            {
                builder.Append(value);
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Then in my _Layout.cshtml. (Towards the bottom)

```
<div id="Partials" style="display: none;">
        @Html.WritePartials()
    </div>
```

Comment: This looks good, and I think your solution is the closest to my question. I think it's "likable". I mean MVC is basically kind of a skeleton, we have to customize it all the time (at least in my past experiences), especially if one (like currently me) use it for rather a Web API like backend than classic MVC. A project has to be irrealisticly simple not to need any customizations. Thanks, I will try to use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a solution to this problem with Razor/partial views that I know of.

You should take a look at [Knockout Components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) (introduced in version 3.2) which were designed to address this problem.

Knockout components can render a template and a viewModel in a variety of ways. The template and view model are only defined once and re-used as many times as required.

If you use a module loader like requireJS (Knockout allows any loader to be used) it can also load templates and scripts dynamically on demand. Components can also be nested and re-used. That should cover your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I know about KO components, but I heavily rely on Razor when rendering even KO templates. I have many helpers to reduce coding.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási, If you were to create a controller that returned partial views instead, you could possibly have the best of both worlds.  I've never tried, but if you return PartialView() instead of View() that would allow you to use the razor code and KO Components together.(Or Require.js)